# How to customize the route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get a page with the following address:
http://localhost:3000/admin/users/1/check_user_restart_passes/1/check_restart_passs_weeks, but I do not know how to configure the route

My `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :admin do
  get "/:admin_user_id/dashboard", to: "admin_dashboard#index", as: :admin_dashboard
  resources :admin_users, except: [:show]
  resources :users, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :show, :check_pass] do
  member do
    get "check_user_restart_passes"
    get "check_user_restart_pass_weeks"
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::AdminsController
  def check_user_restart_pass_weeks
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_restart_pass_weeks = UserRestartPassWeek.where("user_id = ?", @user.id)
  end

  def check_user_restart_passes
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_restart_passes = UserRestartPass.where("user_id = ?", @user.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: what issue you are facing? Is there something you want to achieve this by using routes and you are unable to design the route? Please share the requirement or the issue/error you are facing here.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace :admin do
  get "/:admin_user_id/dashboard", to: "admin_dashboard#index", as: :admin_dashboard
  resources :admin_users, except: [:show]
  resources :users, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :show, :check_pass] do
    resources :check_user_restart_passes, only: :show do
      get "check_user_restart_pass_weeks"
    end
  end
end
```

This will generate the following route:
`/admin/users/:user_id/check_user_restart_passes/:check_user_restart_pass_id/check_user_restart_pass_weeks`